# Como guardar o endereço dos elementos iguais entre vetor e matriz?

Tags: r

estou com uma dúvida, gostaria de pegar o elemento `a[1]` e comparar com  `b[1,1]` e contabilizar como acerto, depois o elemento `a[2]` comparando com `b[2,1]` e assim sucessivamente, sempre por coluna. Depois quero comparar o `a[1]` com `b[1,2]` e contabilizar como certo, depois o elemento `a[2]` com o elemento `b[2,2]` e assim sucessivamente. Posteriormente retornar a coluna de b a qual obteve mais acertos.

```
set.seed(1)
a = sample(1:3, 4, replace = T) 
b = matrix(sample(1:3, 20, replace = T), ncol = 5, byrow = T)
```

A resposta desejada seria coluna 2 ou 5 que se empatarem escolho uma das colunas aleatoriamente.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro. Você quer comparar o vetor `a` com cada uma das colunas da matriz?

Comment: Isso, elemento por elemento.

Comment: Editei uma besteirinha na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
> set.seed(1)
> a = sample(1:3, 4, replace = T) 
> b = matrix(sample(1:3, 20, replace = T), ncol = 5, byrow = T)
> a
[1] 1 2 2 3
> b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    3    2    2
[2,]    1    1    1    3    2
[3,]    3    2    3    3    2
[4,]    3    3    1    2    1
> comparacoes <- apply(b, 2, function(x) x == a)
> comparacoes
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> somas <- colSums(comparacoes)
> somas
[1] 2 2 0 0 2
> b[,nnet::which.is.max(somas)]
[1] 1 1 3 3
```

Use o `apply`, para comparar coluna a coluna os elementos do vetor com os da matriz.
O `colSums` para identificar a quantidade de "acertos" por coluna.
E o `which.is.max` para pegar o máximo, e caso exista empate, pegar aleatóriamente.

Só achei estranho que você fala que o resultado poderia ser a coluna 2 ou 5, mas aparentemente a 1 também cai nesta situação.

Comment: Eu esqueci da coluna 1. Mas de acordo com seu código a saída do mesmo não é as colunas que mais acontecem, ou seja, 1, 2 ou 5.

Comment: é sim... veja o vetor somas: ele é 2 p/ as as colunas 1, 2 e 5. o código seguinte já seleciona uma dessas colunas aleatóriamente, no caso ele pegou a coluna 1. se você quiser que saia um vetor com 1,2 e 5 use `which(somas == max(somas))`.

Comment: Entendi. Eu usei `sort(colSums(comparacoes))` e consegui verificar. Muito grato.